# minisplit for moutain house

Tags: hvac

We bought a mountain house that has only electric-resistance heat (mostly baseboards, plus a couple of in-wall units with blowers).  To reduce electricity consumption, I want install a ductless minisplit heat pump for the main common living space (living/dining/kitchen) on the upper floor of the house.  The lower floor contains the bedrooms, and I will continue to rely on electric baseboard there (at least for the time being) since bedrooms are usually kept considerably cooler, plus it'll be rare for all three of them to be occupied.   Because the house is at 4000+ft elevation, I would use the minisplit little if any for cooling (nobody in the area has A/C).

I am unsure what size unit to install, as well as the number and placement of the indoor unit(s).

See the floor plan below.  The area is about 875 sq-ft.  The house was built in 2001, so presumably pretty good insulation, and double-pane windows (but lots of them on the west wall). Ceilings are vaulted, sloping from 8ft up to 11-1/2ft.   The DoE website specs a winter design temp of 15 degrees for the county, but the house is about 1000ft higher than the reference, so I assume 10 degrees.

I've talked to two knowledgable sources.  One says 18K btu/hr (or maybe even 15k) is the right size, that to go larger would cause the unit to not be able to throttle down low enough, during shoulder seasons, to avoid short-cycling; the other guy says the first guy is an idiot, and I should go at least 24K.  First guy pointed me to this calculator, and I get about 19K heating capacity required, for the entire upper floor.

https://hvac.betterbuiltnw.com/Site/Building.aspx?BuildingId=9740

I'm leaning towards the low choice, because that separate NE bedroom/bathroom/closet has its own electric baseboard, plus the big room has a propane gas-log fireplace.

The other question is about the indoor units.  I'd like to have only one unit - to avoid a second line-set, and because there's one central location where I can easily route the line-set from the basement, up through a closet on the lower floor, and to the spot marked by a red 'X' in the floor plan.  This is a very central location, and the room has a ceiling fan, so I hope it will provide enough circulation into the entire room.  I'd also much prefer a wall unit, although it can be as low as 6ft above floor level; a floor-mounted unit would require an undesirable furniture re-arrangement, and there are many fewer choices for such units.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

10 degrees **above** zero? Easy peasy. Much more choice in units at that temperature rather than mine - but then, mine will be more efficient at that temperature than the ones that only just manage it. But the much less expensive "self-install" ones (if you are so inclined) actually work at that temperature so it might pay off for you.

Window area and level of insulation are the real factors here.

I heat two floors of just over 1000 square feet each in a -15F climate with one wall-mounted 12K BTU head (each with its own compressor, as it's more efficient that way) per floor. I turn off the upper floor (I leave the fan on to circulate, and sometimes turn on an additional circulating fan) when load gets very light.

If you have a lot of window area (even good windows are terrible insulation .vs. even typical walls) and more typical insulation in your 875 sq feet you MIGHT need to go as big as 18K BTU/hr.

### But enough with the hand-waving. you might have real data and precision available

If you have your power bills archived or can get that data, you can know to a much better level of approximation what you'll need, since you have been heating with resistance heat. If your power company uses smart meters and gives you 15 minute or 1-hour data to download, you can get **very** precise about your (whole house, not just this floor) heating load, at 3412 BTU/KWh - just look at your winter overnight power usage in the coldest months. That will give you real data on your as-built heat load in your precise location.

Comment: We just bought the place.   I think POCO will give me monthly bill amounts (along with kwh usage) but that's only so much help, not knowing how much it was occupied.

Comment: Actually, the baseboard is all in the bedrooms.   The big room where I want to put the minisplit is heated by two wall-mounted electric resistance blower heaters.   Each is on a 30amp breaker, so perhaps as much as 30*240*80%*3.412 = 19653 btu/hr, or a total of almost 40K btu/hr.  Maybe I can get the faceplates off them and see how much they really are, or use a clamp-on ammeter at the breaker connection.

Comment: Doesn't matter baseboard .vs. wall mount blower as far as KWH usage - it's all resistance heat, it all comes out the same. It's **highly unlikely** that your resistance heat is operating full bore at max capacity, so get as much actual KWH used data as they will give you and work from there. Since it costs pretty much the same and there's no penalty for oversizing, (it just cycles off more) I expect resistance heat to be over-capacity as installed. How much power was actually used is the important data.

Comment: It might honestly be worth it (galling, but worth it) to put metering on those heaters and live through one January (Northern Hemisphere - presumably July for Southern) in order to accurately size your replacement heat based on real load. HVAC estimates are notoriously bad and generally fudge too big.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't need to be all that cold outside.  The btu/hr per degree of temperature differential should be pretty linear, i.e. pretty similar regardless of outside temperature.   So I wait till it goes down to 40 degrees (pretty common here ) and how hard the electric-resistance heaters work to get it to 100 degrees in the house.

Comment: Examined the two in-wall heaters.   They are dual-rated 4000/3000 watts, website says factory wired at higher wattage, and 13K btu/hr.   I shall contact the previous owner and see if he thought they were adequate or overkill or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with "BTU" numbers on heat pumps - those typically refer to the air conditioner mode, which you have little interest in.

Think about the resistive electric heat you now have.  Does it comfortably keep your house warm all days of the year?  Figure out the "wattage of heat" that is right for you.   Now here's the trick.  Your resistive electric heat has a COP (Coefficient of Performance) of 1.0000, meaning you get 1.00 watts of heat (3.41 BTU/hr) for each watt of electricity you use.

The COP of a heat pump is variable based on outdoor temperature.  If you don't want that problem, look at a ground-sourced heat pump, but the latest heat pumps respectable COP down to surprisingly low temperatures.

Modern heat pumps can run at or below COP 1.0, making them their own emergency heat... but since you already have baseboard heaters that are dirt cheap to maintain, why add the wear & tear to the heat pump engine?

But you need to get data from the manufacturer about the heat pump's performance at all the temperatures you **might** get.  (You don't want to be like Texans who were blindsided by their arctic freeze and cracked a lot of water pipes).

The deciding factor on heat pump size will be the machine's performance at your reasonable worst-case temperature.  If they give you BTU by temperature, that's great, but otherwise if they give you COP by temperature, you can multiply that by power consumption to get *effective* wattage of heating.

- COP x power used in watts = useful heating in watts
- COP x power used in watts x 3.41 = useful heating in BTU

Comment: I suppose it depends on who makes your heat pump as to what the ratings mean. For my mini-splits, the nominal number is the cooling, and the heating is actually a bit more than that. As with the OP's plan, I very rarely put them into cooling mode (other than trying to remember to exercise them every 2-4 weeks in the "off" season)

Comment: @ecnerwal I would not expect a number, but a curve.  Well I'd expect a number on the outside of the box, but digging into the data sheet should present a curve, or at least a table.  That's what you need.  The marketing claim, plus $8, will buy a small coffee at Starbucks.

Comment: "The BTU Number" (max output) is a number. The COP is a curve. The Max BTU output takes more energy at low temperatures as the COP falls. The maximum heat output does not change.

Comment: @ecnerwal heat output can't exceed COP x breaker trip, and shouldn't exceed that x 0.8.  something must yield... and those are the corner cases to mind.

Comment: Yes, "something yields" - the 2 or 3 amps goes up to 9 or 10 amps, the breaker is in no danger of tripping. These are, of course, inverter-drive cold climate minisplits.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateUkraine and others.  Yes, I understand all this technical stuff about btus, COP, etc.  Manufacturers do specify units according to both heating and cooling performance, and I pretty much only care about the former.  And there are plenty of units that can provide plenty of heat at the lowest temperatures I'm likely to see there.

Comment: I've found an awesome website, that gives pretty comprehensive stats on virtually all the minisplits you can buy.   Here's the page for my current leading contender: https://ashp.neep.org/#!/product/51830/7/25000///0. It is a bit curious that its meximum heat output is higher at 5 degrees than at 17 degrees, but it's plenty (if 18K is the answer to my first question).   The other key number is the minimum heat output at 47 degrees, and that's an amazingly low 2800 but/hr; that means it can gracefully handle cool temps without cycling too much.

Comment: My further research, and some of the answers and comments here, are convincing me that 18K btu/hr unit is plenty.   If need be, I could employ the propane fireplace during extreme cold.   Or just leave one of those two existing 4000watt electric resistance heaters in place, until I'm sure I'm good.   I only need to free up one circuit for the minisplit (I'll probably put in a little 240v-only subpanel, in case I want to add another minisplit for the lower/bedroom floor at some point) and each of the 4000watt units is on its own circuit.

Comment: I am still agonizing though, on whether I can get by with one indoor unit (at the red 'X) and it being wall-mounted - rather than having two indoor units and/or having to choose among the very limited choices of floor-mounted type.

Comment: Single wall mount should be fine, based on my install working fine with one per floor that's bigger than your floor. They (should, and if not, you need to find out when shopping and buy a different one - mine do) blow air downwards when in heat mode, very effectively yet very quietly.

Comment: So 18K wall-mount unit it is.    There's a name-brand one (think big mountain in Japan) that heats fine down to 5 degrees outdoors.  It can also turn down to 2800 btu/hr at 47 degrees (less than a hair dryer), so I don't need to worry about it being too big.   And the outdoor unit max dB is in the 40s.

Comment: Problem is, I believe the big names (we all know who they are) are better quality, and have better specs such as I quoted.   But without professional install, they have no warranty.   Maybe I can find a pro who'll let me run the electric, mount the outdoor unit, and drill all the holes for the inter-unit bundle ?  Tell him he can walk away if he shows up to do the indoor unit and line-set and decides I'm an idiot.

Comment: @RustyShackleford The freon work HAS to be done by a pro and warranty requires they do the whole job.  But you can do *a lot*. #1 is the *right-of-way* for the lineset: a hairy, open-ended and expensive wildcard for the installer, and their bid reflects that. So I say if you the homeowner can pre-install those lineset **routes** e.g. with conduit, so they bid it knowing that pulling the lineset will be a 2-minute task, should help a lot.  Plus pre-wire the electrical.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I had in mind.   I guess I can't install the indoor unit though, because the freon lines have to be connected before it's installed.   Still it's a lot I can do.   I'm confused though.  You say warranty requires pro does whole job, but then seem to say it's ok for me to do the stuff I mentioned - so pro isn't doing whole job, really.   I guess it's comes down to whether pro is willing to state to mfg'er that they did the install, period.

Comment: @Rusty Watch some Youtube videos on mini-split installs, and pay very close attention to the fitment issues, glitches and annoyances that suck up most of the installer's time. Your job is to make sure none of those exist, the installer puts the paper template on the wall and gosh, there's an empty line-set conduit *exactly to the mm* where the template wants it, an electrical conduit exactly in the right place, the mounting screws even line up on the studs (or there's a plywood backer waiting). So the work the pro must do, goes like butter.  Show the installer that prep work is done.

Comment: Yeah, got it.   I've actually got a local friend who installs them (doesn't want to install in mountain house, 3hr drive away) who will let me tag along on one of his installs as a sort of unpaid helper.   Should be invaluable.

Comment: Technical question though: you mentioned conduit.  Need that for 240vac power to outdoor unit, of course.   But usually I see that inter-unit cord bundled with the lineset and drain tube, all wrapped up with tape.   Are you saying that whole bundle needs to go into conduit ?   FWIW, it'll come down through the corners of closets on both floors, and then across the ceiling of the basement and out the block wall.   I was hoping that could just be the taped-up bundle, only breaking the cable out into its own conduit right before I got thru the block wall.

Comment: @Rusty no, there's no requirement for a lineset to be in conduit, but it might make the installer's job a lot easier if it was there to use. I would not want a loose exposed line-set in any reachable space, as damage to the line-set will be VERY costly to repair. That'd be a good place for conduit maybe.

Comment: Sure, it'd be slick to run some (maybe 3") conduit through those closets, at least the one on the lower floor.   Could even use plumbing grade (lots cheaper than electrical) since it's not a code requirement.

Comment: Is 3" I.D. DWV PVC (including two 45-degree elbows fairly close together) enough room for the lineset/wiring/drain bundle ?   Probably 1/4"-1/2" lineset.

Comment: @RustyShackleford yes as long as they are sweeps.

Comment: On second thought, I'm going to use lineset cover in the upstairs closet, and PVC in the downstairs one.   Will make things a lot easier - specifically, attaching the lineset to the lines from the indoor unit.

Answer (score -2):

Alternate/additional methods to increase the comfort during cold times, especially in seldom used weekend houses or if the heating system is too weak - and/or to save much energy and money:

1. Bed heat mattress pads.
2. Hair dryer next to the bed for instant warming in very few seconds. Can also serve as instant sauna and replaces a 30 minute hot shower to get the blood circulation going in the morning woth way less energy. Does also partly desinfect the bed: bacterias, viruses, ticks, fleas, lice etc. have little chance to survive the 60 to 150 °C hot air stream. Needs only a tiny amount of energy, since the air in the bed will be heated up in a few seconds.
3. Another hair dryer close to the outdoor shoes can remove any moisture and any olfactory nuisance in a few seconds. Can also be used to warm up a the inner side of  jacket or cloak in a few seconds before leaving the home.
4. For chairs a car heated seat cushion plus variable switched mode power supply can produce a cosy atmosphere just as quickly as in a car.
5. Sitting at a desk (home office) can be more comfortable with no. 4. plus an adaptation of the far east Komatsu concept.
   Long sleeves/towels/bed linen etc. hanging from the table to the ground at 3 or 4 sides ( more layers=better isolation) build a quite isolated area where a small thermostatic electric heater (300W) warms feet and legs.

4 and 5 should be controlled by a motion sensor adaptor (with 5 min. delayed turn- off time).

All 5 points need nearly no energy compared to traditional room heating.

Moisture can be easily monitored by a unit with 3 wireless sensors plus built-in sensor.

To reduce/avoid moisture, "dark-airing" should be used, i.e. airing the rooms at night resp.  preferably before sun rise in the morning, since the air conveys statistically the least amount of water at that time.

Comment: I'm not among the downvoters (can't be bothered, rarely do unless outright wrong/dangerous), but this in no way even approximates answering the question.

Comment: @Ecnerwal 1. "To reduce electricity consumption," is the main issue, since this is the begin of the second sentence after the short introduction sentence. 
2. The question which size of heat pump is needed turns out to be another problem.

The answer clearly 
1. shows how to save energy and money in this case, which could be also interesting for other readers.
2. helps to answer the 2nd question, since a heat pump which normally would be too small could be "healed"/supported by these methods to get the needed comfort.